# How to get UTXOS and Transactions related to a specific address without using Bitcore?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcore

I am developing a wallet for [HappyCoin](https://github.com/happycoinmaster/Happycoin) which is similar but different fork of Bitcoin.

Since this coin doesn't have addressindex rpc methods(getaddressbalance, getaddressdeltas, getaddressmempool, getaddresstxids, getaddressutxos), I can't get utxos and transactions for a specific address.

Since it is quite different from Bitcoin I can't use bitcore-lib or bitcore-node.

How can I get utxos and transactions related to a specific address using legacy rpc methods?

Here are [the rpc methods](https://github.com/happycoinmaster/Happycoin/blob/master/doc/RPC%20console.md) this coin supports.

I've tried with listunspent and listtransactions but these only work with local wallet address not other addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try first importing the address as a watch-only address into your wallet using:

`importaddress <address> [label]`

Once the rescan is complete (it has to scan the entire blockchain for all transactions related to this address), which can take over an hour.

You should then be able to use the wallet commands to list unspent and tx'es.

Comment: I can't use this solution because the wallet app I'm developing is not a full node wallet. The wallet will refer to my full node server for checking utxos and transactions of a user's mobile wallet. Because whenever a user creates an address it will take over an hour for initialization.
Then should I add a separate utxo database on my server to accomplish this feature?

Comment: Yes that is the only way to do it with the restrictions you mentioned, as the full node does not maintain a database indexed by address